# PHP echo construct - array problem

Tags: php

```
echo "$gooshgoosh[$i]['num']";
```

Does anyone here know why it echos

```
array['num']
```

Comment: Post more code, and watch your language.

Comment: echo is not a function, it's a language construct.

Comment: @evolve lol, "watch your language", nice job layin' down the law. :D

Comment: Please avoid unnecessary swearing. It's disrespectful of others, even if you personally don't feel that it's a problem.

Answer (score 6):

PHP will only evaluate interpolated expression to the first array index, or the first attempt to dereference an object.  This means that these won't work as expected:

```
echo "$array[id1][id2]";    // like "{$array[id1]}[id2]"
echo "$object->obj1->obj2"; // like "{$object->obj1}->obj2"
```

You can force PHP to evaluate the entire expression using curly braces:

```
echo "{$array[id1][id2]}";
echo "{$object->obj1->obj2}";
```

In your particular case, PHP was evaluating `"$gooshgoosh[$i]"`, which resolved to an array. Array to string conversion yields the string "array", so that string was substituted in yielding `"array['num']"`.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because of quotes: PHP does not understand, that ['num'] is array index. Try this:

```
echo $gooshgoosh[$i]['num'];
```